# MvxTableViewCell not disposed

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, memory-leaks, mvvmcross

I have a memory leaks issue.

I basically have a MvxTableViewController databound to a observablecollection.  I create a MvxTableViewController and add it to my Controller as a child and I add the view as a subviews.

Problem is, the Cell in the table never gets disposed, leaking memory.

```
// When the view gets removed from the stack, the cells disposed method is never called and I can see the memory not going away, using the Xcode Instruments tool.  The table dispose gets called as expected. but not the cell
public partial class ParticipantTableViewCell : MvxTableViewCell
{
    readonly UILabel _nameLabel = new UILabel();
    readonly UILabel _locationLabel = new UILabel();
    readonly PictureContainer _pictureView = new PictureContainer(7.0f);

    public ParticipantTableViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

        ContentView.AddSubviews(new UIView[] {_nameLabel, _locationLabel, _pictureView});
        _pictureView.TransparentBackground = true;

        SetupConstraints();

        // Since this view is readonly, I've removed the actual binding code
        // and instead manually init each views.
        this.DelayBind(() => {
            _nameLabel.Text = ((ParticipantViewModel)DataContext).Name;
            _locationLabel.Text = ((ParticipantViewModel)DataContext).Location;
            IsSelected = ((ParticipantViewModel)DataContext).IsSelected;
            _pictureView.AvatarImage.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Media/" + ((ParticipantViewModel)DataContext).AvatarUrl);
        });
    }

    void SetupConstraints ()
    {
        ContentView.Subviews.ForEach(v => v.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false);

        ContentView.AddConstraints(
            _pictureView.Height().EqualTo().HeightOf(ContentView),
            _pictureView.Width().EqualTo().HeightOf(ContentView),
            _pictureView.WithSameCenterY(ContentView),
            _pictureView.Left().EqualTo(6.0f).LeftOf(ContentView),

            _nameLabel.Left().EqualTo(10.0f).RightOf(_pictureView),
            _nameLabel.Right().EqualTo().RightOf(ContentView),
            _nameLabel.Bottom().EqualTo(2.0f).CenterYOf(ContentView),

            _locationLabel.Left().EqualTo(10.0f).RightOf(_pictureView),
            _locationLabel.Right().EqualTo().RightOf(ContentView),
            _locationLabel.Top().EqualTo(4.0f).CenterYOf(ContentView)

        );
    }

    // never called
    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}

    class FriendsView : MvxTableViewController
{
    protected new FriendsViewModel ViewModel { get { return (FriendsViewModel) base.ViewModel; } }

    public FriendsView ()
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        TableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        TableView.RowHeight = 60;
        TableView.ScrollEnabled = false;

        var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(TableView, typeof(ParticipantTableViewCell));
        TableView.Source = source;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FriendsView, FriendsViewModel>();
        set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.YuFitFriends);
        set.Apply();
    }
}
```

Anybody got an idea as to why my cells are leaking ?

thanks
pat

Answer (score 1):

```
**// never called**
protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Do you expect this will be called magically? NO!

Dispose is just a another method in your class which you should call when you don't want its instance anymore.

And also, you should dispose all the disposable instances in your class (eg: PictureContainer) in this Dispose method. Also, make sure you unsubscribe from any event subscriptions. Just calling base.Dispose doesn't release any reference in this class.

Answer (score -2):

I got a working solution... The bugs seems to be with how MvvmCross register cells for reuse.  If I derive my own class from MvxBaseTableSource  instead of using MvxSimpleTableSource and I create the cells differently, I get everything to dispose properly:

```
class MySource : MvxTableViewSource
{
    public MySource (UITableView tableView) : base(tableView)
    {

    }

    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (ParticipantTableViewCell.Key) as ParticipantTableViewCell;
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new ParticipantTableViewCell ();

        return cell;
    }
}
```

and in my tableviewcontroller, I use MySource

```
    var source = new MySource(TableView);
```

Now everything gets collected fine!